# How to fetch aws cognito user pool attribute.email data into website console log ,after successfully logined with microsoft AD

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

**My Workflow is that**

I redirected my website to **AWS Cognito with Microsoft AD** for sign-in. So when any user was logging into Microsoft and after successfully login redirected to my website. this is working perfectly.

Now I need typescript code for the "Who **currentAuthenticatedUser** user attribute **email address** print into my **website console log**.".